# Findall() in re module not giving me the same result as search

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i trying to get a list of phone numbers with and without area code (Lets just pretend phone numbers are 9 digits)

```
import re

def message_6():
    phone_regex = re.compile(r'(\d\d\d-)?\d\d\d-\d\d\d')
    mo = phone_regex.findall("Call me at 966-123-412 or 237-128")
    print(mo)

message_6()
```

however the list i get is ['966-', '']
i want it to output a list like this ['966-123-412', '237-128']

Comment: Did you mean ```\d\d\d-\d\d\d(-\d\d\d)?```. Also, check your regex online like here: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex only captures what is inside parenthesis `()`. So you have to put whole regex in them:

```py
import re

def message_6():
    phone_regex = re.compile(r'(\d\d\d-)?\d\d\d-\d\d\d')
    mo = phone_regex.findall("Call me at 966-123-412 or 237-128")
    print(mo)

message_6()
```

but then tuple of two values is returned.
Why?
That is because you have two capture groups. One for the whole number and one for the optional part. So you can insert `?:` at the start of capture group to ignore it in result.

```py
import re

def message_6():
    phone_regex = re.compile(r'((?:\d\d\d-)?\d\d\d-\d\d\d)')
    mo = phone_regex.findall("Call me at 966-123-412 or 237-128")
    print(mo)

message_6()
```

That works as you need.

Also it can be shortened to `r'((?:\d{3}-){1,2}\d{3})'` if you want.

Comment: but for same example 81724891791-12491-401-2401-40 your code gives ['791-124', '401-240']

Comment: @Pygirl But that is the same behaviour author of question asked for. Because otherwise is just an opinion what should be accepted and what not. But your answer also mathed sth like `'12'` and that would be better example I think.

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks for clarifying.